# Nested route values not populating edit Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `belongs_to` relationship between a `map` and a `row`. A `map` has_many `rows`.

For some reason, when I try and edit a row, even when it is populated in my database, it is not showing the values when I try to edit this row. Why would this be? Below is the `_form.html.erb` and the `edit.html.erb` file.

#### Edit.html.erb

`<%= render 'form', row: @row %>`

#### _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for [@map, @map.rows.build], method: :post, url: map_rows_path do |form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :timeframe %>
    <%= form.text_field :timeframe, id: :timeframe %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :standards %>
    <%= form.text_field :standards %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :content %>
    <%= form.text_field :content %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :skills %>
    <%= form.text_field :skills %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :resources %>
    <%= form.text_field :resources %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

If I try `Row.last` in the rails console it confirms that this row is populated with data. I am assuming this has something to do with the way the form is setup however I am not familiar with these relationships. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you are passing row to form where `<%= render 'form', row: @row %>` but in Actual edit form you are using a variable, @map and building a blank row object by saying `@map.rows.build`, hence the row object will be a new object with out any values.

Based on your code change it to following and see. ( I am assuming you are setting up @map object in your edit action in controller)

```
<%= form_for [@map, row], method: :post, url: map_rows_path do |form| %>
```